# Compile each file from file list in Make

Tags: c, makefile

The problem is the following. I have a list of .c files in several directories that I wish to compile, one by one, into a .o file, located at BUILD_DIR folder, to be later linked. They are appended to the SOURCE_FILES_FREERTOS variable. The Makefile code section that attempts to perform this is:

```
OBJ_FILES_FREERTOS = $(SOURCE_FILES_FREERTOS:%.c=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)

# Build the Operating System Library
freertos: ${OBJ_FILES_FREERTOS}

${BUILD_DIR}/%.o : $(dir ${SOURCE_FILES_FREERTOS})/%.c
    -mkdir -p ${BUILD_DIR}
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ${INCLUDE_DIRS} -MMD -c $< -o $@
```

However, it does not work, saying there is no rule fore the first target file:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'build/../../../FreeRTOS/Source/stream_buffer.o', needed by 'freertos'.  Stop.
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The error message comes from the `freertos` target and you have not even shown the part of the Makefile that has that target. It look like that target has dependencies with object paths different to the target and rules you have shown.

Comment: The dependency on a file in a non-existing directory is not going to end well.  You can use order-only dependency to ensure the directory is created: `${BUILD_DIR}/%.o : $(dir ${SOURCE_FILES_FREERTOS})/%.c | ${BUILD_DIR}` then have $(BUILD_DIR) target that does the mkdir.

Comment: If you haven't look up VPATH which the cleanest way of searching for source files one place, and build them in a another.

Comment: Look at my latest edit.

Comment: It's _highly_ unlikely that `$(dir ${SOURCE_FILES_FREERTOS})/%.c` can be what you want.  The `$(dir ...)` function expands to the directory of _every word_.  If that variable contains `dir/foo.c dir/bar.c dir/baz.c` then this will expand to `dir/ dir/ dir//%.c` which can't be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

From a top-down perspective we first declare the objects to be part of the library:

```
OBJECT_FILES_FREERTOS := $(patsubst ...)
libfreertos.a: $(OBJECT_FILES_FREERTOS)
```

I cannot create `OBJECT_FILES_FREERTOS` from the variables in the question. You'd have to add more to it or figure it out yourself. Below I assume that all object files have `$(BUILD_DIR)/`-prefix and the same directory structure as the source it is derived from (which is a pain since Make does not create necessary directory hierarchy for you, but that's just how Make rolls).

Make now tries build object files from source files. By default searching for source files in the same directory as where the object files are expected to be. This is where it becomes tricky, since the source files (from looking at your error) is not in the source tree, making a relative path to god knows where. You need a different source-to-object map, here using static rules:

```
$(OBJECT_FILES_FREERTOS): $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(FREERTOS_SRC_DIR)/%.c
```

`No rule to make target` means it cannot find a rule to build the file, most often because the source file is missing and Make does not know how to build it from nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`freertos` has a dependency on `build/../../../FreeRTOS/Source/stream_buffer.o` but you don't have any rules that cover that file.  This is your root cause for the build failure.

The pattern rule suggest you are putting the object files in $(BUILD_DIR) and not 3 levels up from it.  This means that the pattern rule doesn't apply in this case.